# NSMutableData replaceBytes vs appendData

Tags: ios, nsdata, nsmutabledata

In terms of performance (speed and memory consumption) . What do you prefer?

CASE1:
Attaching `NSData` to the beginning of some `NSMutableData`.

CASE2:
Attaching `NSData` to the end of some `NSMutableData`.

CASE3: (This one goes obviously to replaceBytes)
Inserting `NSData` into the middle of some `NSMutableData`.

Comment: In a naive implementation, everything except append-to-end is `O(n * m)`, append-to-end is `O(n)` if `n` is the length of the data to be appended, and `m` is the length of the data to be appended to. Not sure how naive Apple's implementation is.

Comment: CASE2 has the best chance to perform best as it might be possible to increase the byte-buffer with something like `realloc`. But in the worst case all Versions will perform similar, as reallocating memory might fail and so the same amount of data will be copied to a new place in memory.

Comment: @JonathanCichon I am afraid you misunderstood the question. I would like to get the question answered (mind the question title) in all of the 3 cases. The question IS: replaceBytes? Or appendData?

Comment: appendData will most likly perform best, except when you use replaceBytes without increasing the size of the buffer and just overwriting existing data.